# JavaScript to Html

Tags: javascript, html, command-line-interface, html-generation

Given a web page with JavaScript code, I would like to generate a resulting html automatically (either via CLI tool OR using some library in some language)

For example, given `test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to get as a result

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="demo">Hello JavaScript!</p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you serve the page on your localhost then scrape it with phantom?

Comment: I think @Tim is trying to parse a html file and insert text in the <p> tag. BeautifulSoup should do the work.

Comment: How about using a WebClient and getting the resulting dom from it? I imagine you could do this but haven't tested it, hence the comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Daniel_L The page is served from the host I have no control

Comment: @DarrenGourley are you speaking about htmlunit http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/? If so then it brakes during the processing of my page unfortunately

Comment: @YuWu not exactly. The JavaScript might invoke some external url and modify the current page's DOM. A given example is simple and serves for demo purposes only.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith thanks, will check their APIs http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/

Comment: Sorry @Tim, I may have gotten the wrong end of the stick with your question, for some reason I assumed it had a .NET tag. WebClient is baked in to .NET and allows you to request Web pages as you would in a browser, only programmatically.

Comment: You're misunderstanding @Daniel_L's comment, which is actually a correct answer (almost). Just run a phantom program which loads the page (from the host), then grab the full page content.

Comment: @torazaburo the comment was modified. I will definitely try http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html thanks

Comment: Screen capture is close to what you want, but not exactly. You'll want to grab the entire page HTML and save it to file somewhere most likely.

Comment: @torazaburo do you have perhaps an example? If you feel you have right solution, you can write an answer and get it accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is based on the comment of @torazaburo

In fact, the [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) is capable of evaluating javascript and producing html.

Here is how it could look like, executing `phantomjs load_page.js path_to/test.html`

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    page_address;
var fs = require('fs');
if (system.args.length === 1){
  console.log('Usage: phantomjs ' + system.args[0] + ' <page_to_load:http://www.google.com>');
  phantom.exit();
}
page_address = system.args[1]

page.open(page_address, function(status){
    console.log('Status:' + status);
    if (status === 'success' ){
      fs.write('phantom_result.html', page.content, 'w')
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search, it looks like [watin](http://watin.org) will do what you want.

It's aimed at automated testing, but when it hits a page it will execute all js as well as ajax calls etc. Looks like you can grab the resulting html from it too.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this soon. Are you familiar with some other library for some open source stack (java, scala, clojure)?

Comment: Sorry @Tim, as per my comment above I thought this question had a .NET tag. I'm not aware of any other libraries that would do this.